# Apache httpd dynamic URL redirection

Tags: linux, apache, redirect

I've a problem while redirecting dynamic URL to backend server. For example, below is the URL

https://10.192.1.1:9080/primary/webrechargereturn?amount=4685&response_code=14000&signature=5dcedca895b5093ea5223ca99a5def4f9180f1d89ba3bbdedc160520f4f2198b&merchant_identifier=lYHzMLpA&access_code=Lev9uNwYXD96MpaMHVwV&payment_option=SADAD&customer_ip=192.71.175.30&language=en&eci=ECOMMERCE&fort_id=149502322600094674&command=PURCHASE&response_message=Success&authorization_code=wt6RiWBNk7Hj9Aue5Foh&merchant_reference=49486cee-e39a-4668-a082-c4e7089d65e4&customer_email=abc@gmail.com&currency=SAR&sadad_olp=SABBP2P_UAT2&status=14

and I want it to be redirect to http://10.192.1.2:8080/primary/webrechargereturn

I am already using proxypass directive for static URL which are working absolutely fine. But dynamically, I am unable to find URL.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the issue? If so, did the answer below help you in the process?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something on the lines of the following?

```
RewriteRule   ^/primary/webrechargereturn[?].*   /primary/webrechargereturn  [R]
```

See http://rewrite.rcbowen.com/book/